# typescript assign value to class property per key string

Tags: typescript

I have two objects. One class named CreateUserDto and an interface IUser. IUser has many properties that CreateUserDto doesn't have. I get an IUser and want to create a new CreateUserDto with it and fill every propertie that those two have in common.

This is what I have come up with:

```
// user is IUser, creadeUserDto is CreateuserDto
Object.keys(user).filter(key => key in createUserDto).forEach(key => {
        // key only has propertie keys that both have. Both always have the same type
        // Both test and test have the same types
        let test = createUserDto[key as keyof CreateUserDto];
        let test2 = user[key as keyof CreateUserDto];

        // Those are working
        test = test2;
        test = user[key as keyof CreateUserDto];
        
        // Those do not work...
        createUserDto[key as keyof CreateUserDto] = test2;
        createUserDto[key as keyof CreateUserDto] = user[key as keyof CreateUserDto];
      });
```

I don't get why the first two are working but the last two, where I need one of them, prefered the last one, will show me those errors:

```
createUserDto[key as keyof CreateUserDto] = test2;

Type 'string | number | boolean | Permission[] | Date | UserGroup[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
```

```
createUserDto[key as keyof CreateUserDto] = user[key as keyof CreateUserDto];

Type 'string | number | boolean | Permission[] | Date | UserGroup[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: What does "prevered" mean?

Comment: Maybe you could [edit] the example code to be a [mre] that I could paste into my own IDE and see what you're seeing.  Right now `user` and `CreateUserDto` are not defined, so I can't easily proceed.  Ideally the only problems I'd have with your code are the problems you are asking about, and not unrelated things like type definitions.

Comment: `user` is just an interace with a few properties like `username`, `firstname` etc. `CreateUserDto` is a class that contains the same properties as `ùser`  except that `user` has like 3 more that `CreateUserDto` doesn't have. Example: `User` has `username`, 'id', `firstname`. `CreateUserDto` only has `username`, `firstname`.